# Anderson’s exercise 8.3 on “generating and cogenerating”

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am reading “Anderson and Fuller - Rings and Categories of Modules (2nd edition, 1992)” 
and I am trying to find a solution of exercise 8.3 on page 112, which says:

Let $M$ be a left $R$-module. Show that if $M$ cogenerates a generator, then $M$ is faithful.

So, $M$ cogenerates a generator, say $M$ cogenerates $X$ and $X$ is a generator, where $X$ is a left R-module.

(1) $M$ cogenerates $X$, by Corollary 8.13.(1) (page 109) the reject of $M$ in $X$ is zero, that is:

$$ Rej_X (M) = \bigcap \{ ker(h) \text{  |  } h \in Hom_R (X,M) \} = 0 $$

(2) $X$ is a generator, this means that $X$ generates $_R R$, that is, $R$ as a left $R$-module.

Then, by Corollary 8.13.(2) (page 109) the trace of $X$ in $R$ equals $R$, that is:

$$ Tr_R (X) = \sum \{ im(h) \text{  |  } h \in Hom_R (X,R) \} = R $$

(3) It follows that there are finitely many $f_i \in Hom_R (X,R)$ and $x_i \in X$, $i=1, 2, \cdots ,n$ such that

$$1 = f_1 (x_1) + f_2 (x_2) + \cdots + f_n(x_n)$$

( I do not know if we need this in the proof. )

(4) Proposition 8.22 on page 111 says that the annihilator of $M$ in $R$, that is:

$$ l_R (M) = \{ r \in R \text{  |  } rM = 0 \} $$

equals the reject of $M$ in $R$, that is:

$$ Rej_R (M) = \bigcap \{ ker(h) \text{  |  } h \in Hom_R (R,M) \} $$

Thus

$$ l_R (M) = Rej_R (M) $$

(5) Now we have to show that M is faithful, that is, the annihilator is zero, that is,

$$ l_R (M) = Rej_R (M) = 0 $$

So, we have to prove that if $s \in l_R (M) = Rej_R (M)$ then $s = 0$

Take $s \in Rej_R (M) = \cap \{ ker(h) \text{  |  } h \in Hom_R (R,M) \}$

Then, for all $ h \in Hom_R (R,M)$ we have $h(s) = 0$

Also, because $ l_R (M) = Rej_R (M) = 0 $, we have $s \in l_R (M)$

So, for all $m \in M$ we have $sm = 0$

Take $x \in X$

Then, for all $ h \in Hom_R (X,M)$ we have $h(sx) = sh(x) = 0$, because $h(x) \in M$

Thus, for all $ h \in Hom_R (X,M)$, $sx \in ker(h)$

Thus, by (1) above,

$sx \in Rej_X (M) = \cap \{ ker(h) \text{  |  } h \in Hom_R (X,M) \} = 0$

Therefore, $sx = 0$, for all $x \in X$

So, $s \in l_R (X) = Rej_R (X) = \cap \{ ker(h) \text{  |  } h \in Hom_R (R,X) \} = 0$

Then, for all $ h \in Hom_R (R,X)$ we have $h(s) = 0$

Now I am stuck and I do not know where I am heading to.
Can someone, please, help me to finish this proof ?

Answer (score 1):

Saying that $M$ cogenerates a generator $G$ means that $G$ embeds in a direct product of copies of $M$. Indeed, since $\operatorname{Rej}_G(M)=0$, if we take all homomorphisms $f\colon G\to M$, the natural map
$$
G\to M^{\operatorname{Hom}_R(G,M)}
$$
defined by $x\mapsto (f(x))_{f\in\operatorname{Hom}_R(G,M)}$ has zero kernel.

If $r$ annihilates $M$, then it also annihilates $G$. Since a generator is necessarily faithful, then $r=0$. Therefore $M$ is faithful as well.

Why is a generator $G$ faithful? Because $R$ (as a left $R$-module) is an epimorphic image of a direct sum of copies of $G$, thus any $r$ that annihilates $G$ has to annihilate $R$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am working on it, That will take a while.

Comment: I do understand your answer, thank you.

Comment: @Steenis When an answer is useful it should be upvoted so as to push it from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in line of my argument in my original post,

and I am embarrassed because I was so close and I did not see it.

We proved $sx = 0$, for all $x \in X$, and we have to show that $s=0$

In (3) we found
$$1 = f_1 (x_1) + f_2 (x_2) + \cdots + f_n(x_n)$$
So
$$s = f_1 (s x_1) + f_2 (s x_2) + \cdots + f_n(s x_n)$$

Then, for each $i=1, 2, \cdots ,n$: $ s x_i=0 $, because $x_i \in X$ thus

$$s = f_1 (0) + f_2 (0) + \cdots + f_n(0) = 0$$

Now, we are ready, because thie proves that $M$ is faithful